# Page route prevents OnGet() receiving query argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor-pages

I'm porting a WebForms application to Razor Pages, and I'm using the following route to prevent breaking one of my URLs.

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Resources/CharClass", "/Resources/CharClass.aspx");
});
```

But using the code below, when I use the URL */Resources/CharClass.aspx?page=500*, `page` is always null.

**cshtml**

```
@page "{page:int?}"
```

**cshtml.cs**

```
public void OnGet(int? page)
{
    //
}
```

The argument seems to work okay for pages that aren't routed this way. How can I have both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem you have is with the name of the parameter - `page`. This seems to conflict with the `Page` property of the PageModel class, and nothing is bound during model binding. You can however access the query string value using traditional methods:

```
var page = Request.Query["page"];
```

EDIT: Just seen that this is partly covered in a reply to your other question on the issue: [Razor page link ignores route argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400305/razor-page-link-ignores-route-argument)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Resources/CharClass", "/Resources/CharClass.aspx/{page?}");
});
```

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question and format your code.

Comment: This adds the page as part of the URL and not a query argument. Also, I though this is basically what the `@page` directive does at the top of the cshtml file.

Comment: If the route ends at your page CharClass, then an additional subroute appended in the URL, automatically gets filled in the query argument